# PDO insert not working with OOP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert, sql-insert

If I try to insert a line to my database, I don't get error or anything, it just simply not working...

Here is my codes:

The insert line:

```
$inserted = $user->create(array(
    'fb_id' => $userId,
    'name' => $userData->getName(),
    'mail' => Input::get('first-time-email'),
    'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('first-time-pattern')),
    'img' => $userPicture,
    'last_ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
    'code' => $salt
));
```

The User class:

```
public function create($fields = array()) {
    return $this->_db->insert('users', $fields);
}
```

The DB class:

```
public function insert($table, $fields = array()) {
        $keys   = array_keys($fields);
        $values = null;
        $x      = 1;

        foreach($fields as $value) {
            $values .= "?";
            if($x < count($fields)) {
                $values .= ', ';
            }
            $x++;
        }

        $sql = "INSERT INTO {$table} (`" . implode('`, `', $keys) . "`) VALUES ({$values})";
        if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

And the DB class's query part:

```
    public function query($sql, $params = array()) {

    $this->_error = false;

    if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
        $x = 1;
        if(count($params)) {
            foreach($params as $param) {
                $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                $x++;
            }
        }

        if($this->_query->execute()) {
            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
        } else {
            $this->_error = true;
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried to print `$sql` and apply it directly on DB? No?

Comment: Here is my sql variable: **INSERT INTO users (`fb_id`, `name`, `mail`, `password`, `img`, `last_ip`, `code`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)**

Comment: Seems legit. Next you should modify `query` method to check erros. Use `errorInfo` function to see what's wrong.

Comment: The problem could be that `$fields` is not numeric, but you use unnamed placeholders. Try using `array_values($field)` on calling `query()`.